# How to use div id and class in $(document).ready() method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

jQuery method calls first **on-image** class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.no-image').remove();
});
```

There is two **no-image class** here. I need to remove both.

```html
<span title="599" class="599" id="local-thumbnail">
  <span class="no-image">No cover image available</span>
</span>
<span title="599" id="amazon-thumbnail">
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/P/8125906258.01.TZZZZZZZ.jpg" alt="" class="item-thumbnail"></span>
<span style="block" title="599" class="8125906258" id="gbs-thumbnail">
  <span class="no-image">No cover image available</span>
</span>
```

And how to use id to remove the specific no-image in jQuery method.

Comment: `$('.no-image').remove();` should work ... does it? any errors in the console when you try? ... for ID's it's `"#id"`

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking... _"I need to remove both"_ and _"remove the specific no-image"_ seem to be at odds

Comment: did you want to remove just the image inside the first span perhaps?  i.e. `"#local-thumbnail .no-image"`

Comment: My CMS fetch the book cover image from amazon through ISBN. There is some result that has no image cover and it shows no book cover image is some of the item. So, how to remove that one through jQuery method

Answer (score 2):

To remove the no-image span element inside the #local-thumbnail element use this (as per suggestion of @Jaromanda X in the comments):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#local-thumbnail .no-image').remove();
});
```

To remove the #local-thumbnail element itself (containing a .no-image element) use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#local-thumbnail .no-image').parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: My CMS fetch the book cover image from amazon through ISBN. There is some result that has no image cover and it shows no book cover image is some of the item. So, how to remove that one through jQuery method

Comment: @Billu I editted my answer.